# Authorization Policy Attribute returns 403 and User.IsInRole returns false but claims are present WEB API Azure AD (Single Tenant)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

**Setup**
I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web app configured with Azure AD. I have an ASP.NET Core Web API configured Azure AD.

I obtain the token from Azure AD in the client web app and use it when requesting resources from the Web API, this works fine.

**Issue**
The '[Authorize(Policy = 'policyName')]' attribute returns 403 and User.IsInRole() returns false in the WEB API controller, however when I remove the authorize policy attribute and check the user claims object, I can see the role present. Please check the image below

***Claims Image***
[image]

***RoleClaimType Image***
[image]

In my startup file I have configured token validation parameters of roleClaimType to be roles

```
`services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>{
// Use the groups claim for populating roles
options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
});`
```

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();


        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            // Use the groups claim for populating roles
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
    
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(Constants.AssignmentToAccountCreatorsRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.CAN_CREATE_ACCOUNT));
            
        });


        services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));



        //services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<DbContext>().Database.Migrate();
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

        //TODO: Replace CORS configuration
        services.AddCors(c => c.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => {
            policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44385", "https://someweb.net/")
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyMethod();
        }));
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddScoped<ConfigurationModel>();


        //services.AddScoped<GraphProfileClient>();
        //services.AddScoped<GraphEmailClient>();
        services.AddMemoryCache();


        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "NAPI", Version = "v1" });

        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
     
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"));
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();

        }




        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
 

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have configured for `ASP.NET Core MVC` or `ASP.NET Core Web API` ?

Comment: ASP.NET Core Web API

Comment: It seems that using `HasClaims` attribut eshould resolve your issue and get you expected claims and role.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes, exactly! **HasClaims** returns the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the options for AddAuthorization() policy in the startup.cs contains a RequireClaim method which takes in the claimType and the allowedValue(s). [RequireClaim(String, IEnumerable)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireclaim?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authorization-authorizationpolicybuilder-requireclaim(system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string))))

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AssignmentRoleRequired", policy => policy.RequireClaim("roles", "canDoSomething"));

        }); //Startup.cs


[Authorize(Policy = "AssignmentToRoleRequired")] //For Controllers
```

Similarly the User Object also contains a method called HasClaim(), that takes in the claimType and the allowed value.

Within a controller [HasClaim(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.hasclaim?view=net-7.0#system-security-claims-claimsidentity-hasclaim(system-string-system-string))

```
   var result = User.HasClaim("roles", "canDoSomething"); //returns true
```